# CMake Error: mismatch for the compiler version between your conan profile

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I'm on MacOS.

This is my error :

> CMake Error at build/conanbuildinfo.cmake:625 (message):
> Detected a mismatch for the compiler version between your conan profile
> settings and CMake:
>
> Compiler version specified in your conan profile: 11.0
>
> Compiler version detected in CMake: 12.0
>
> Please check your conan profile settings (conan profile show
> [default|your_profile_name])

and here's my cmakefile:

```
   project(Babel)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
add_definitions("-fPIC")

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

find_package(Qt5Widgets CONFIG REQUIRED)

file(GLOB_RECURSE BABEL_SRC PATH ./sources/*.cpp)

include_directories(${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH})
add_executable(babel ${BABEL_SRC})
target_link_libraries(babel ${CONAN_LIBS} Qt5::Widgets)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If yes how?

Comment: @Dialecticus the response is down  :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple-clang recently updated to version 12.0, but your default profile, created before, still contains version 11.0.

This error is good, it is protecting you from changing compiler version and not realizing binaries will be different.

You can update your default profile, go to your userhome `~/.conan/profiles/default` and change `compiler.version=11` for `compiler.version=12`.

If you are using a Conan version older than 1.29.2, you need to upgrade, as Conan 1.29.2 adds also `12` to the available versions in the default settings (you can see this file in `~/.conan/settings.yml`. Editing this settings file and adding version `12` manually to the `apple-clang` versions can also work for this case.

Comment: I have installed LLVM and clang 11.1.0 via homebrew intentionally as Apple clang does not support the Address Sanitizer and Leak Detector. How would I adjust the settings that my v11 should be used to build dependencies?

Comment: Already updated the conan profile and still have the same issue, it seems there's a cache somewhere... Maybe there's a step missing in this answer